# Website Forms to iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, web

I've been researching for ages and still cannot find an easy solution that perfectly. So i stopped and figured i was going about this project the wrong way. All i need is an easy solution.

My project requires me to make a website that has forms (fields include images, text, urls, colors). When the user submits this form, somehow (THIS IS THE KEY QUESTION), gets sent to Xcode so that it can be used in and iPhone app.

My questions: What is an easy to use program to make a website that can do what i said? How does my website connect to Xcode (supply it with the data)? Is it possible for my app to check for newly submitted info?

Keep in mind that i don't have much coding knowledge as far as websites and i only a little about making iPhone apps (Yes, i have made some but not as advanced as this)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: O'Reilly sells a book specifically about web development for the mobile environment.  That's where you want to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build an IOS app that can retrieve user submitted data from the server.

Your form will have to post the data to the server where it is stored in your database.  Images will have to be uploaded to the server as well.

You can then build a server-side api that returns data to the IOS device upon request.  You can have your IOS app regularly request data from the server, receive the response and store what you need on the device.

There is a lot more to it of course, but from what I can gather from your post, this is what you're looking to do.

Comment: yes exactly. how? as far as a tutorial, how to make a website that can connect to a server that can do this. Code? Steps? Etc

Answer (score 0):

The workflow you describe doesn't make any sense.

It starts out easily enough: you have a website that has a form with a submit button. No problem there. Hitting submit likely does a POST to a server somewhere. Again, no problem.

Then you say the form data has to ultimately end up in Xcode. This is where things are really muddled. Xcode is a programming IDE for Mac OS X. I'm not sure how or what it has to do with handling data from a Web form. The two things are, for all intents and purposes, completely independent technologies.

Please describe in much more detail exactly why you think you need to "send data to Xcode". Otherwise, your question, as written, is unanswerable.